# No driver selected running netsh to activate tunnel for ipv6

Tags: windows-10, ipv6, netsh

I am trying to run netsh commands to activate a tunnelbroker tunnel in Windows 10.  The first command works fine.  When I attempt the second command (netsh interface ipv6 add v6v4tunnel interface=IP6Tunnel localaddress=xxxxxxx remoteaddress= 216.66.22.2) I get the error "There is no driver selected for the device information set or element."

I cannot find an answer for this, even from tunnelbroker.  Does anyone have a suggestion?  This is driving me up a wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an Insider issue. Microsoft decided to step down on IPv6 transition technologies as of Redstone 4 (1803). Unfortuntely, instead of just deactivating it, they stopped providing the tunnel driver at all (nettun.inf, tunnel.sys). It's unclear at this point whether Microsoft intents to fix this or not.

Comment: Under "Features we're no longer developing", Microsoft now lists "IPv6 transition technologies": https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/deployment/planning/windows-10-1803-removed-features

Comment: 6in4 is a "Direct Tunnel", so MS states this had been disabled by default since always. Which is weird as it clearly was working before. But I now understand it as starting the tunnel would be the activation. However, this doesn't work anymore. Nettun.inf hosts the driver (tunnel.sys is still present, though), but is not available anymore in 1803. Since this whole feature set is marked deprecated, it suggests MS won't fix it. However, Teredo/ISATAP/6to4 are also listed in nettun.inf and they work more or less (they just can't connect to the servers).

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer: Don't use Windows 10 insider builds for IPv6. It seems they broke IPv6 with some of the more recent builds. I started out from scratch with the current version (Fall Creators, I believe), and the commands ran without issue.

Comment: Also the RTM 1803 Spring Creators Update suffers from this problem. That was the official final build, which was later withdrawn. So I fear the problem will still be present in 1804 soon to be released.

Comment: Still broken in final 1803 build 17134.48. Also still broken in 1803 insider build 17661.1001.